# Banco de dados externo não está carregando no android

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite3

Eu preciso fazer uma aplicação `Android` que acessa um `servidor`, baixa arquivos `.s3db` e consulta sobre os arquivos baixados. Eu consigo baixar normalmente para `data/data/meu-pacote/databases/` e também consigo fazer operações sobre esses arquivos. Mas há um problema:

Por alguma razão, eu só posso fazer operações em `arquivos.s3db` ao abrir o aplicativo pela segunda vez. Primeiro é preciso instalar, clicar em baixar novamente (desta vez ele não baixa pois ja tem um arquivo de mesmo nome na pasta, mas ainda assim preciso clicar) depois fecho o aplicativo e abro novamente. Aí sim o botão que faz a consulta funciona normalmente ...

Ja tentei usar `threads` e `activitys` mas não funciona de jeito nenhum ... alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser isso? Utilizo `android studio`

Comment: acompanhou os logs pelo log cat?

Comment: Aparentemente seu aplicativo não está sabendo atualizar o banco de dados recebido do servidor. Você poderia nos mostrar a parte do seu código que faz essa atualização?

Comment: Precisas de esclarecer melhor o problema, podes mostrar o teu código?